# How does this shell script that contains C source work?

Tags: c, shell

```
//usr/bin/make -s "${0%.c}" && ./"${0%.c}" "$@"; s=$?; rm ./"${0%.c}"; exit $s
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("chmod and run\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the "//" in the beginning? and do I have to save the script as a C file?

Comment: This is actually *not* a bash script -- in many circumstances it will be executed with `/bin/sh`, not bash, so using bash-only features would cause it to fail in those circumstances. Tagging adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `//` is probably a way to make this file a valid C99 program as well as a valid shell script.

In C99, `//` starts a comment. For the shell, an absolute path beginning with `//` may have a special meaning, but I have yet to see a system where it is not equivalent to a single slash. The POSIX wording has the gory details:

> A pathname consisting of a single <slash> shall resolve to the root
>   directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully
>   resolved. If a pathname begins with two successive <slash> characters,
>   the first component following the leading <slash> characters may be
>   interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than
>   two leading <slash> characters shall be treated as a single <slash>
>   character.

**How it works**

The file must have a `.c` extension. Then do as commanded,

```
chmod 755 file.c
./file.c [args ...]
```

This will run

```
make -s "${0%.c}"  # make -s file
```

Since `make` has a built-in rule to create `file` from `file.c` by running the C compiler, this even works without a `Makefile` nearby. Then it runs

```
./file [args ...]  # because "$@" expands to the arguments provided above
```

and saves the exit status with `s=$?`, deletes the compiled program with `rm ./file` and exits before it runs into a syntax error (if it attempted to run the C source as a shell script).

Comment: The slashes thing is, I believe, true everywhere **but** at the start of the path. I believe that is, technically, reserved and may mean other things (though I don't know anywhere that this actually happens).

Comment: @EtanReisner, IIRC, the reserved `//` prefix is actually meaningful on systems using AFS (though, indeed, those are rare these days).

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for the info. I have provided now the POSIX wording to make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

That line is a (`C99`/`C++`) comment.

"as a C file" doesn't mean anything. That file would, customarily, have a `.c` extension if that's what you meant though.

This file is a [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29). That is it is valid code in more than one language. In this case `C99`/`C++` and `sh`.

If you execute that script as a shell script it will compile itself as a `C` program, execute that binary, remove that binary and exit.